# Web Push Notifications - multiple sub-domains issue?

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, notifications

I just developed Web Push Notifications, but I've got a problem.

My website has multiple sub-domains. For example:

(1) root - `www.example.com`
   (2) sub - `www.data.example.com`
   (3) sub - `www.cool.example.com`

As you could understand, every time when I visit cool.example.com, browser wants permissions for the sub-domain, not for root domain. Of course, it's logical but is it possible to ask permissions for root domain regardless of the fact that I've been visited sub-domain?

Answer (score 2):

Where have you placed your service worker ? It seems like you have different service worker for each sub-domain, correct ?
Anyway, if you place your service worker at the root of your website (and maybe have the subscription javascript also run from there), the scope of the worker will be the entire origin (this service worker will receive fetch events for everything on this domain)

Read https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/ for more information